# How can I make an ActionSheet cell not dismiss when clicked?

Tags: ios, swift

I want one of the options to do nothing when clicked.  It's basically a placeholder. It won't have a title, and it's just white.

```
func actionSheet(sheet: UIActionSheet, clickedButtonAtIndex buttonIndex: Int) {
    if sheet.tag == 1 {
        var title = sheet.buttonTitleAtIndex(buttonIndex)
        if title == Constants.EmptyTitleActionSheetItem{
               //do nothing. don't dismiss.
        }else{

               //something real was clicked. perform actions and continue dismissal
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not sure though, but I don't think it's possible to avoid dismissal. The alternative solution I see here is that you can present the Action-Sheet again when the button where you need "don't dismiss" is tapped.

Comment: @AtifAlvi that sounds like an answer to me :)

Comment: @ClayBridges You may Up-Vote the comment then :P

Answer (score 5):

There a are 2 choices I see.

1. As I mentioned in the comment above, I don't think it's possible to avoid dismissal. The alternative solution is that you can present the Action-Sheet again when the button where you need "don't dismiss" is tapped, with **animate = FALSE**.
2. You can build your own actionSheet **OR** use a third-party open-source library.

Comment: This is what he means by **animate = FALSE**, set the `animated` property to false `present(actionSheet, animated: false, completion: nil)`. The only problem is the animation still occurs, it's just faster.

Answer (score 0):

Only option is to `create a custom` or use `third party`

Third party Action Sheet are given below:

[JGActionSheet](https://github.com/JonasGessner/JGActionSheet) - A feature-rich and modern action sheet for iOS.

[AHKActionSheet](https://github.com/fastred/AHKActionSheet) - An alternative to the UIActionSheet with a block-based API and a customizable look. Inspired by the Spotify app. It looks a lot better live than on the GIF (because compression).

Answer (score -1):

put return statement in that if block.

```
if title == Constants.EmptyTitleActionSheetItem{
  //do nothing. don't dismiss.
    return;
    }
```

Comment: It still dismisses the Action Sheet when clicked.